# array schema store empty values

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongodb

I want store values in mongodb using node controller but it will store an empty array inside mongodb

1).This is node controller using to accept the req parameter

```
this.childQuestionId = function(req, res, next){
    try{
        var userObj = {
            'child.quiz.questionId' : req.params.questionId,
            'child.quiz.score' : req.params.score,
            //'child.quiz.time' : req.params.time
            'child.quiz.time' : new Date().toISOString()
            };

        var childupdate = new childQuiz(userObj);

        childupdate.save(function(err,data){
            if(err) return next(err);
            console.log("Data saved successfully");
            res.send(data);
        });            
    }catch(err){
        console.log('Error While Saving the result ' +err);
        return next(err);
        }
}
```

2).This is mongodb schema using to store the value. Here i am using array quiz schema to store values is array

```
 child:{
    quiz:[
        {
        /*questionId:{
          type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
          ref: 'commonquestions'
          },*/
          questionId:{type:String},
          score:{type:Number},
          time:{type:String}
        }
        ]
    }
```

3).This is my json result sending values using postman

```
{
"__v": 0,
"_id": "57a43ec68d90b13a7b84c58f",
"child": {
"quiz": []
}
}
```

Comment: Could you test the 'childupdate' object ? Try to parse it then print out in console log to see what is inside?

Answer (score 0):

Try with this code in your controller

```
this.childQuestionId = function(req, res, next){
try{
    var userObj = {
        'questionId' : req.params.questionId,
        'score' : req.params.score,
        //'time' : req.params.time
        'time' : new Date().toISOString()
        };

    var childupdate = new childQuiz();
    childupdate.quiz.push(userObj);

    childupdate.save(function(err){
        if(err) return next(err);
        console.log("Data saved successfully");
        res.send(childupdate);
    });            
}catch(err){
    console.log('Error While Saving the result ' +err);
    return next(err);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB save() function accepts 2 parameters, `document` and `data`, but in your code, you use a callback function. Should you check it out?

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.save/#db.collection.save